# How to output string after a specific character?

Tags: sql

I have a query :

```
  select 
        right( ltrim(rtrim(MEMBER_NAME)),(len(ltrim(rtrim(MEMBER_NAME)))- charindex('/',ltrim(rtrim(MEMBER_NAME))))) as member_name

    from member
```

where on the member_name I want to ouput the last name and first letter of the name after '/'.

The problem im having is with the query above it's outputting some names wrong depending if they have longer names.

For example if we have a name 'suarez-suarez/john doe' is outputing 'john doe' when it should be suarez-suarez J' 
or 'suarez/john doedoe' is outputting  'john doedoe' when it should be 'suarez j'.

How can i get it to output the string with the last name and first letter of first name?

I created a http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c7a74/1

```
 create table member (member_name varchar(50));
    insert into member (member_name)
    values ('suarez-suarez/john doe'),
    ('suarez/john doedoe'),
    ('suarez/john d'),
    ('mejia/suzy m'),
    ('orozco/dady rammmon');
```

Comment: I'm unclear on what the problem is here. Your question says "'suarez-suarez/john doe' is outputting 'john doe' when it should be outputting 'john doe'", which seems like it's outputting exactly what you've asked (and expected). You've asked for the characters to the right of the `/`, by using `right()` and `Len() - CharIndex()` portions of your `SELECT`and that's exactly what you're getting.

Comment: read again your question and expected output,edit it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

im also a little confused but given the names you have listed, if you want surname + space + first initial then this would do the job.

```
SELECT LEFT('suarez/john doe', charindex('/', 'suarez/john doe') - 1) + ' ' + SUBSTRING('suarez/john doe', charindex('/', 'suarez/john doe') + 1, 1)
```

Comment: change where i have put the name to your field.

`SELECT LEFT(member_name, charindex('/', member_name) - 1) + ' ' + SUBSTRING(member_name, charindex('/', member_name) + 1, 1)`